# Uncaught Error: Object of class Core could not be converted to string

Tags: php, oop

I have two PHP files, one is "Pages.php" which has `class Pages{}` and the second one is "Core.php" which has `class Core{}`. I included the "Pages.php" into the constructor of  "Core class" and trying to invoke a public method named `home()` from the "Pages class". But it shows the following error :

> Uncaught Error: Object of class Core could not be converted to a string.

```
class Core {
    protected $currentController  = 'Pages';
    protected $currentMethod  = 'home';
    protected $params = [];

    public function __construct() {      
        require_once '../app/controllers/' . $this->currentController . '.php';
        
        $this->currentController = new $this->currentController();
  
        $this->currentController->$this->currentMethod();        

    }   
    
}
```

If I invoke the method like this

```
$a = $this->currentMethod;

$this->currentController->$a();
```

It works fine...
But I want to know that Why I'm not able to invoke the method like this `$this->currentController->$this->currentMethod();`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use this syntax because of the order of interpretation.

If you want to do it in one line, you could use `{}` to "interpret" the content as a block.

```
$this->currentController->{$this->currentMethod}();
```